# How to restore Mac OS after installing Linux

Tags: restore, internet-recovery

I'm going to install Linux on a Macbook Air (from ~2013), and I plan on replacing the entire contents of the hard disk (OS, recovery partition, etc).

If I want to restore Mac OS, will Internet Recovery work? Do I really just need to hit Command+Option+R during boot? Should I back up something to make restoring easier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the questions asked, yes.

However, have a look at [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT204904) and [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314).

That said, personally I'd create a USB macOS Installer and set it aside for when you want to reinstall. Have a look at: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

Also, dont forget to make proper backups of your data before formatting the HDD/SSD. You might even want to have a Time Machine backup. Have a look at: [How to use Time Machine to back up or restore your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201250)

Comment: Glad I asked this *before* installing.

Comment: @David Ehrmann, Dont forget to make proper backups of your data before formatting the HDD/SSD. You might even want to have a Time Machine backup. Have a look at: [How to use Time Machine to back up or restore your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201250)